Nodemailer not working after hosting on aws with nginx server.got error "error : {code: "EAUTH", command: "API"}"
in my NextJS project, the nodemailer is configured as a server component. it works fine locally but not after being deployed in AWS with Nginx.
The folder structure is src/app/api/mail/route.ts
I'm using the application-specific password from Gmail.
 const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.GMAIL_USER,
        pass: process.env.GMAIL_PASS
      }
    });

nginx config
server {
listen 80;
server_name MY PUBLIC_IP;

location /{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

Expecting to send email through the cloud as well as locally
